# Twitter typeahead add custom data to dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using `twitter typeahead` to show category suggestions which works fine for me. 
 The problem is with the display of sub-categories. If a `category has sub-categories`
 `then expand/collapse icon` is shown along with the suggestion, if the user selects one them the sub-categories has to be shown below it, i have succeeded in the display part but `cannot update the dataset` of typeahead so that when the user selects one the sub-categories it should be displayed in the input. `Please use keyboard on Jsfiddle because i have tried only in keypress`. The following is my json array

JSFIDDLE [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e0zqL2qd/2/)

```
[{
    "id": "38",
    "value": "Entertaintment",
    "parent_id": "27",
    "children": "1",
    "childCategories": [{
        "id": "28",
        "value": "Movies",
        "parent_id": "38"
    }, {
        "id": "29",
        "value": "Sports",
        "parent_id": "38"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "40",
    "value": "eeen",
    "parent_id": "27",
    "children": "1",
    "childCategories": [{
        "id": "41",
        "value": "een child 1",
        "parent_id": "40"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "41",
    "value": "een child 1",
    "parent_id": "40",
    "children": "0",
    "childCategories": false
}]
```

I have tried the following:

```
_onEnterKeyed: function onEnterKeyed(type, $e) {
    var cursorDatum, topSuggestionDatum;
    cursorDatum = this.dropdown.getDatumForCursor();
    topSuggestionDatum = this.dropdown.getDatumForTopSuggestion();
    //My custom condition, if category has children show sub-categories below 
    if (cursorDatum.raw && cursorDatum.raw.children == "1") {
        //below line is my failed try  
        //this.dropdown.updateChild('',cursorDatum.raw.childCategories,false); 
        var that = this, onSuggestionClick, onSuggestionMouseEnter, onSuggestionMouseLeave;
        var childHTML='';
        $('.ttchild').remove();
        //adding the sub-categories to dropdown
        $.each(cursorDatum.raw.childCategories,function(i,v){
            childHTML += '<div class="tt-suggestion ttchild"><div class="suggestions"><span>'+this.value+'</span></div></div>';
        });
        $(childHTML).insertAfter('.tt-cursor');
        return;
    }

    if (cursorDatum) {
        this._select(cursorDatum);
        $e.preventDefault();
    } 
    else if (this.autoselect && topSuggestionDatum) {
        this._select(topSuggestionDatum);
        $e.preventDefault();
    }
},

//This is my custom function trying to update the dataset, but i know its totally wrong.
updateChild: function updateChild(query,childs) {
    var that = this;
    this.query = query;
    this.canceled = false;
    this.source(query, render);

    function render(childs) {
        if (!that.canceled && query === that.query) {
            that._render(query, childs);
        }
    }
},
```

JSFIDDLE [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e0zqL2qd/2/)

e.g: The Entertainment category has subcategories movies and sports.

Hope any one would help me....

Comment: I was hacking on it a little bit, but it's not saving the values correctly. It also looks like the 'haschildren' button is added after the html is generated, so it's adding extra of those because the indexing is wrong.

Hopefully this is helpful to you in some way, but digging through the whole [typeahead.bundle file](http://pgsuae.info/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.js) you've been hacking on is a bridge too far right now.

http://jsfiddle.net/82hmLprb/1/

Comment: All the data is added through bloodhound. It creates the tokens,hashes and cache. I think everything will be ok if we can update the items in bloodhound object

Comment: @Nouphal.M Hey, why haven't I got my bounty yet, I solved your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit v.2**

I [refactored](http://jsfiddle.net/8nqk6qrr/) again, now it works perfect.

I removed my previous edits and refactored `onEnterKeyed` function as follows

```
var dataSet = this.dropdown.datasets[0];

// childHTML is replaced by childDom
// var childHTML='';
var childDom = $('<div></div>');
$('.ttchild').remove();
$.each(cursorDatum.raw.childCategories,function(i,v){

    var div = $('<div class="tt-suggestion ttchild"></div>');
    div.append('<div class="suggestions"><span>'+this.value+'</span></div>');


    var suggestion = v;

    // TODO console log this is duplicated from dataset
    var datasetKey = "ttDataset", valueKey = "ttValue", datumKey = "ttDatum";


    // this is what makes it show in the input box
    // set these data for the child element.
    div.data(datasetKey, dataSet.name);
    div.data(valueKey, dataSet.displayFn(suggestion));
    div.data(datumKey, suggestion);

    childDom.append(div);
});

// childHtml is replaced by childDom
$('.tt-cursor').append(childDom.children());
```

**Deprecated Edit v.1**

I [refactored](http://jsfiddle.net/123qywb5/) my solution, now it works as expected.

I removed my previous edits and added this line in the `getSuggestionNode` method.

```
for (var key in suggestion.childCategories) {
    var value = suggestion.childCategories[key];
    $el.append(getSuggestionNode(value));
}
```

*Deprecated Below*

I [solved](http://jsfiddle.net/v24eop96/) your problem, though it needs improvement on your part.

```
// I added this line
// add the child nodes to the suggestions.
suggestions = suggestions.reduce(function(res, num) { res.push(num); for (var i=0;i<num.children;i++) res.push(num.childCategories[i]);  return res; }, [])

// nodes are calculated based on suggestions
// but child nodes are not added to suggestions so their data is not set (see below line)
nodes = _.map(suggestions, getSuggestionNode);

// inside the suggestions.map function
// here .data sets the necessary values required to render the input on cursor change.
// since child nodes are not mapped they are ignored.
$el = $(html.suggestion).append(that.templates.suggestion(suggestion))
    .data(datasetKey, that.name)
    .data(valueKey, that.displayFn(suggestion))
    .data(datumKey, suggestion);
```

So you don't need a custom `updateChild` function, though I don't know how you implement the dropdown stuff, this solution will add the child to the dropdown and show them instantly, without pressing enter in the parent node. You should configure that on your own.

Comment: The entries are repeating and they are not suggested in the texbox. And the drop-down is part of type-ahead plugin.

Comment: But here the subcategories are showing at startup. I need it to be only shown when press enter on the "entertaintment" entry. i.e what  i am looking for is to add and remove items on "enter" key event and mouse click. I hope you get my point..

Comment: Your refactored link is not valid. How could i see your solution?

Comment: @Nouphal.M It is valid, and it is working, http://jsfiddle.net/8nqk6qrr/. Also If you can't make it work I use a [gist](https://rawgit.com/eguneys/4223852de054ff356862/raw/5db030c5b67aa7fb141cf17557a67af60b3bfcf8/typeahead.bundle.js), try it in your jsfiddle and it will work. You could've just told me that before, and I am looking forward for that bounty.

Comment: Yes it works like a charm. Check whether u got ur bounty. i have accepted your solution

Comment: no, @Nouphal.M bounty has expired, unless you explicitly give it to me I won't get it, so restart the bounty (preferably with double points, because of latency), and give it to me, I spend so much time on it, and I solved it more than a week ago.

Comment: Have granted your bounty. :)

Comment: @Nouphal.M, sorry for bothering you further, I haven't received the bounty, can you make sure you clicked the blue bounty button.

Answer (score 1):

#### Here's a different approach

You could treat each group of `childCategories` as it's own datasource.  Then use the [Multiple Datasets](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#multiple-datasets) paradigm to automatically apply a header for child items.

The second parameter to [`$.typeahead(options, [*datasets])`](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadoptions-datasets) takes an array of datasets. We can convert each set of child elements into it's own dataset like this:

```js
var dataSources = [];
$.each(movies, function(index, movieItem) {
    if (movieItem.childCategories) {
        var bloodhoundEngine = createBlounhoud(movieItem.childCategories, 'value');
        var dataSource = {
            name: movieItem.value,
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: bloodhoundEngine.ttAdapter(),
            templates: {
                header: '<h3 class="typeahead-group">' + movieItem.value + '</h3>'
            }
        };
        dataSources.push(dataSource);
    }
});
```

Notice that we've defined a *header template* for items in this datasource. We can style it like this:

```css
.typeahead-group {
  margin: 0 20px 5px 10px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Elements that were not part of a child group could could all get added as part of a single `ungrouped` datasource:

```js
var ungrouped = [];
$.each(movies, function(index, movieItem) {
    if (!movieItem.childCategories) {
        ungrouped.push(movieItem);
    }
});

function addUngroupedItems() {
    var bloodhoundEngine = createBlounhoud(ungrouped, 'value');
    var dataSource = {
        name: 'ungrouped',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: bloodhoundEngine.ttAdapter()
    };
    // add to first position of array so it doesn't look like it's part of the group above it
    dataSources.unshift(dataSource);
};
```

This solution has the benefit of minimally overriding existing typeahead and bloodhound code while working within the framework to provide grouping functionality.

Also, it provides an intuitive UI for users that might know the name of the name of a child item they're looking for, but don't want to have to click through each category to find it.  Most local searches can trivially search on all fields.

#### [Working Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/xk3pscgx/)

[image: screenshot]

> **Aside**: I would try to avoid modifying the source code  directly.  It makes it very difficult to see where you have made your own modifications.  Instead, try using a CDN for the whole library and writing a plugin or wrapper on top of it.  This will make incoporating future revisions much easier.

Comment: In your example i can't select the element with value "eeen"

Comment: @Nouphal.M, yeah, that's going to be a limitation of this approach.  You could of course add parent items into the unsorted list if you wanted them to be selectable on there own.  Not quite what you had in mind.  But still provides a relatively intuitive interface that showcases some manner of grouping.

Comment: I want to add a expand/collapse button to the dropdown list, if any item has sub-categories and be able to add/remove child elements on the fly.